# awaitMessage on for loop

Tags: discord.js

I'm looking for awaitMessages method to get some answer from predefine questions. So I have about 5 questions, and do a good code, I'm making a loop for BUT it's seems little broken to put awaitMessages on it. Any idea to what to do ? :/

```
chan.send(embed(questions[0], 0)).then(() => {
        chan.awaitMessages(response => response.author.id != myBotId, {
            max: 1,
            time: 6000,
            errors: ['time'],
          })
          .then((collected) => {
            chan.send(`The collected message was: ${collected.first().content}`);
          })
          .catch(() => {
            chan.send('There was no collected message that passed the filter within the time limit!');
          });
      });
```

I have that yet, code working to get an answer.And it was on this loop :

```
for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {};
```

I need a way to do a great code, not copy paste five times the same snippet of code. I'm trying my best to learn :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use `await` and do it like this:

```
let questions = [
    {
        question: "What's your name?",
        answer: null
    },
    {
        question: "How old are you?",
        answer: null
    }
];

for(let i = 0; i < questions.length; i++){
    // Send the question in the current channel
    message.channel.send(questions[i].question);
    // Await for the answer
    let answer = await message.awaitMessages(response => response.author.id !== myBotId, {
        max: 1,
        time: 6000,
        errors: ['time']
    }).catch(() => {
        // If the user doesn't answer to the question, save "The user didn't respond" as the answer
        questions[i].answer = "The user didn't respond";
    });
    // If the user provides a answer, save it
    questions[i].answer = answer.first().content;
}

// Display the result
console.log("First question: "+questions[0].question); // What's your name?
console.log("Answer: "+questions[0].answer); // The answer of the user, or "The user didn't respond" if he didn't respond
```

With this code, you can add as many questions as you want.

Comment: Command is not recognized by the bot (send me 'command not found' : my command error text) and doesn't send the question until I wrote something in the channel. And get sometime an async error :/

Comment: You need to put this in an async function. Can you send the full code of your command to see what is the problem?

Comment: Here is my code : https://pastebin.com/SZ1WX6DM
Output discord : https://imgur.com/a/bggwksc
No error on console.